# Software that can create an intersection, roads and highways

Tags: visual-design

I'm looking for a program that can create an intersection, roads and highways. I checked draw.io and MS Visio but it seems that they don't support the top view of the intersection.

Edit: Additional Info

1. An *image* of an intersection will do.
2. It's OK if it doesn't have cars.
3. It's just for illustration purposes
4. I'm looking for a free or open source, but if it has a price maybe I can also consider it.

I'm looking to create images like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that if you are prepared for a somewhat steep learning curve you consider looking at [Blender](http://blender.org/) 3D modelling tool. While it might be a little overkill for what you are currently doing, (i.e. Plan View only), you can model your roads, intersections, etc., on a single plane initially and consider adding a 3rd dimension later.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Can produce view from any angle including top down
- You can add "cars", etc., and animate
- You can output as image or movie formats
- Add some texture and lighting and you can render to photo-realistic output.
- You can even buy premodelled elements to use from sites such as [TurboSquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/package-street-obj/853533)
- Lots of online help - e.g.: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qoC5pdgTLM) road construction tutorial

Some examples:
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve for the suggestion. Please what particular template or 3D model did you use for the image you posted. I couldn't find that particular premodelled element on Turboquid.

Comment: @Francis - this was an image posted online in one of the blender forums IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, your example illustrations were all top-down vector graphics, such as can be done in Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, or InkScape or Xara.

I don't *think* you need full-on 3D modeling, though if you do, Blender is a really great tool as mentioned before by @Steve Barnes. I fully second his recommendation.

Adobe Illustrator is an industry standard, is expensive, but powerful, and there are decades worth of assets out there for using with it.

Affinity Designer is newer, faster, and way cheaper, but doesn't have the depth of existing assets out there, but given the extreme simplicity of what you're drawing, this shouldn't be a problem.

InkScape is freeware, and open-source, and exists for *nix, Windows and Mac OS - there are assets out there for its use, but they're often... less than professional quality - so *caveat emptor*.

Hope this helps some.